# if statement triggering on wrong input

Tags: javascript, if-statement

well so i'm having a problem with my if statement triggering on the wrong input

an example i have a random number generator and when i get the output 3
it automatically activate the if statement that should activate when it gets 1 or 5

code:

```
var randomnumber;

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    console.log(randomnumber);
}

var LTB = 0; //this is how many times you have bought a lottery ticket

Lottery.addEventListener("click", function() {
    LF(1);
});    

function LF(lottery_number){
    if (lottery_number == 1) {
        randomIntFromInterval(1, 5);
        if (randomnumber == 1 | 5) {
            Points = Points * 2;
        }else if (randomnumber == 2 | 4) {
            Points = Points + 10;
        }else if (randomnumber == 3) {
            Bitcoins = Bitcoins + 1;
        }
    }else if (lottery_number == 2) {
        //i'm gonna add something here later and i have tried removing it
}
randomnumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: @DrewKennedy that´s it

Comment: @DrewKennedy that would always evaluate to true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
randomnumber == 1 | 5
```

Should be:

```
randomnumber == 1 || randomnumber == 5
```

Final result:

```
function LF(lottery_number){
    if (lottery_number == 1) {
        randomIntFromInterval(1, 5);
    if (randomnumber == 1 || randomnumber == 5) {
        Points = Points * 2;
    }else if (randomnumber == 2 || randomnumber 4) {
        Points = Points + 10;
    }else if (randomnumber == 3) {
        Bitcoins = Bitcoins + 1;
    }
}else if (lottery_number == 2) {
    //i'm gonna add something here later and i have tried removing it
}
randomnumber = 0;
}
```

'|' is a `Bitwise` OR, something you're not attempting to do. `||` is a conditional OR. This should correctly give you your `if` statement checks.

Comment: Or, more maintainable, `[1,5].indexOf(randomnumber)`

Comment: is you want to use the `indexOf` method you actually need to compare against -1 `[1,5].indexOf(randomNumber) > -1`  (`[1,5].indexOf(1)` => `0`, which is falsy)

Comment: @lemieuxster Or you could put a tilde in front ;)

Comment: @JonathanGray in front of what?

Comment: @lemieuxster Sorry I thought it was obvious. Just like this: if(~[1,5].indexOf(randomNumber))

Comment: @JonathanGray ah, you know what - it was obvious I just had a mental lapse that negative numbers are still truthy. I am an idiot.

Comment: @lemieuxster We all have our moments lol

Answer (score 0):

`randomnumber == 1 | 5` is not the same as `randomnumber == 1 || randomnumber == 5`

`|` is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and so your expession is evaluating to something like `false | 5` which is cast to `0 | 5` which is just `5` which is truthy and so it enters that first if block.